# FCM: Device token is not valid

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

I have 2 projects in Firebase. One for iOS and the other one for Android app.
In the apps I collect the device token and send it to my php API, where it gets stored in the DB and used in the API to send the push notification to both app users. For the API I'm relying on this [package](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) as the firebase admin sdk.

But when I send the push notification, I get the exception "NotFound", which means that the token was not found in the firebase project.

For the php SDK, I use the private key generated in firebase.